# Using INotifyPropertyChanged in WPF applicatoin

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.6.1

I'm using .Net 4.6.1 with a WPF application. We have an `ObservableCollection` and we want to bind the collection to a listview that needs to have sorting alphabetically and auto updating upon new item in the collection.

I use `CollectionViewSource` and searched here on StackOverflow for updating I need to use `INotifyPropertyChanged`. But for some reason it doesn't work :(.

Object class:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ObservableCollection
{
    public class AlarmTypes : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string name; 
        public AlarmTypes(string _name)
        {
            this.name = _name;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");

            }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XAML file

```
<Window x:Class="ObservableCollection.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ObservableCollection"
        xmlns:componentModel="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
        xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>


        <Grid.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Name="CollectionViewSource" x:Key="src" Source="{Binding alarmTypes }" IsLiveFilteringRequested="True">
                <CollectionViewSource.LiveSortingProperties>
                    <clr:String>Name</clr:String>
                </CollectionViewSource.LiveSortingProperties>
                <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                    <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="Name" />
                </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            </CollectionViewSource>
        </Grid.Resources>



        <ListView x:Name="lstAlarmTypes" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="319" Margin="585,48,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="157" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource src}}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,48,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Name="textBox1"/>
        <Button Content="Add item" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="173,51,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <ListView x:Name="LstNames2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="301" Margin="339,66,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`XAML.cs` code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ObservableCollection
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<AlarmTypes> alarmTypes = new ObservableCollection<AlarmTypes>();
        private ObservableCollection<AlarmTypes> sortedTypes = new ObservableCollection<AlarmTypes>();


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LstNames2.ItemsSource = alarmTypes;

            var alarmType = new AlarmTypes("inbraak");            
            alarmTypes.Add(alarmType);

            var alarmType2 = new AlarmTypes("alarm");
            //alarmType.Name = textBox1.Text;
            alarmTypes.Add(alarmType2);

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var alarmType = new AlarmTypes(textBox1.Text);
            //alarmType.Name = textBox1.Text;
            alarmTypes.Add(alarmType);


        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if the binding doesn't work or it's the property or I still need something else. The first list has a binding just to the Observable collection and that works when inputting data from the textbox. But the second listview that has the collectionViewSource apparently doesn't work. Any ideas whats missing?

Comment: `<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding alarmTypes}" …/>` requires that `alarmTypes` is a public property in the DataContext of your Window. Right now it's a private field. Make it a public property, set `DataContext = this;` and remove the direct ItemsSource assignment `LstNames2.ItemsSource = alarmTypes;`

Comment: if I set DataContext = this; i get nothing

Comment: lsinames2 doesn't matter btw it's the collectionviewsource but I can't seem to call it

Comment: I have found a github from microsoft itself on collectionviewsource and was able to fix some issues for the moment. I have fixed my collectionviewsource which means i can see items in my listview that are sorted. furthermore i can confirm that when i add an item and debug my observable collection has the item in it so now it's definitly only updating problem

Comment: Hi. If the answer below solved your problem please consider marking it as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn `alarmTypes` into a public property.